# Binary insertion, second half of array isn't being called recursively?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to insert `number` into a sorted array of unique numbers such that the new array is also sorted.  My intended operation is as follows:

1. divide array in half until each half is either 1 element or 2 elements
2. if 2 elements: if `number` is between the 2 elements, return `[element1, number, element2]`, otherwise return `[element1,element2]`
3. if 1 element: if `number` is equal to `element`, return `[number, element]`, otherwise return `[element]`

My understanding of how a recursive solution should work is that this breaks the array down until `number` can either be appended to its duplicate or sandwiched between a lower and upper bound, and then new array is assembled going back up the call stack. (and yes I know this doesn't work if `number` is lower than the lowest array element or higher than the highest)

My code:

```
function insertNum(num,sortedSet){
    var returnValue;
    console.log(`sortedSet:${sortedSet}`);
    if (sortedSet.length==0){
        return [num];
    }
    if(sortedSet.length>1){
        console.log('length greater than 1');
        output=splitInHalf(sortedSet);
        if(num>output.first[output.first.length-1]&&num<output.second[0]){
            console.log(`${num} belongs between`)
            return output.first.concat([num]).concat(output.second);
        }
        else{
            return insertNum(num,output.first).concat(insertNum(num,output.second));
        }
    }
    else{
        if(num==sortedSet[0]){
            returnValue=[num,sortedSet[0]]
            console.log(`returning append:${returnValue}`);
            return returnValue;
        }
        else{
            return sortedSet;
        }
    }
}

function splitInHalf(sortedSet){
    halflength_floor=Math.floor(sortedSet.length/2);
    halflength_ceil=Math.ceil(sortedSet.length/2);
    console.log(`halflength_floor:${halflength_floor}`);
    console.log(`halflength_ceil:${halflength_ceil}`);
    first=sortedSet.slice(0,halflength_floor);
    second=sortedSet.slice(halflength_floor);
    console.log(`first:${first}`);
    console.log(`second:${second}`);
    var output=[];
    output.first=first;
    output.second=second;
    return output;
}

console.log(insertNum(7,[2,3,5,6,8]));
```

I'm getting the output:

```
sortedSet:2,3,5,6,8
length greater than 1
halflength_floor:2
halflength_ceil:3
first:2,3
second:5,6,8
sortedSet:2,3
length greater than 1
halflength_floor:1
halflength_ceil:1
first:2
second:3
sortedSet:2
sortedSet:3
sortedSet:3
[ 2, 3, 3 ]
```

Because we never see the output of:

```
sortedSet:5
sortedSet:6,8
```

That makes me think that in the initial call of:

```
insertNum(num,first).concat(insertNum(num,second))
```

which should have the arguments

```
insertNum(7,[2,3]).concat(insertNum(7,[5,6,8]))
```

only the first `insertNum()` call is being made, and the other `insertNum()` call, wrapped in `concat()`, never occurs.  Why not?

Comment: What's the point of this algorithm? Inserting into an array is O(n), so walking the array from the front, finding the insertion point, then inserting it with `concat` or `splice` is going to be much more efficient and easier to write than recursion.

Comment: @ggorlen that's assuming that your array is implemented such that insertion is O(n).  But consider a physical problem: adding a page to the middle of a dictionary stored in a 3-ring binder.  It is much faster to find the insertion point through a binary search, and then add the page via opening and closing the binder, than it is to flip through potentially thousands of pages until the insertion point is found.

Comment: @ggorlen and yes, this solution will still walk through all values of the array anyways, but this can be optimized so that `sortedSet` is only split in half if `number` is between `sortedSet[0]` and `sortedSet[sortedSet.length-1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change code like below.

From

```
output=splitInHalf(sortedSet);
```

To

```
var output=splitInHalf(sortedSet);
```

Comment: damn.... beat me to it.... lol...   exactly right...  without the var your output variable is maintained at global scope... so you're constantly reassigning it... as opposed to re-declaring it within each iteration scope

Comment: That was it!  and thanks @DynasticSponge for the deeper explanation.